# Column 'MyColumn' is constrained to be unique. Value 'abc' is already present

Tags: sql

does anybody know why i getting this.
i have backup from my programs day to day . but after this error Appeared. even last backups not working. i am confused because I DON'T Insert Anything OR Update Anything َAND/OR Delete Anything i get this error when i open myforms , and an odd things is this error Occurs in my startup page where i have ShowDialog methode.

```
FRM_Shares s = new FRM_Shares();
s.ShowDialog();
```

i just remember that i changed a table and coloumn name named Sallery to Salery.
i tried every answer from the web ,i am thinking to rewrite whole project

i use dataset. sql express 2008 r2 sp 2, .net 4 and vs 2012.
thanks in advanced.

Comment: can u give ShowDialog code ?

Comment: it is a dotnet built in code so i don't know

Comment: I am sure the error is not in the given lines. Debug your code and find out which line is actually causing this error. `not working` is not helpful to fix your issue. As your question header says, you are trying to insert a `duplicate` value `abc` to `MyColumn` which is already present. You have your answer in your question header!!!

Answer (score 0):

it was missed from connection string

```
User Instance=True
```

i findout the problem when i checked every exception error from **Debug->Exceptions...** to true.

what is **user instance** anyway? 
Best Regards